# Set Page Title from Custom System.Web.UI.Page class

Tags: c#, asp.net

For some reason i am created my own version of `System.Web.UI.Page` class and inherited the deafult `Page` class. Now i want to set `Title` of every page that using my custom `Page` class on `Page_Init` event.  Can you please suggest me the best way without creating a new version of `Page_Init` method on drrived classes

```
public class MyPage : Page{
    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e){ 
          //do some basic opeation
    }
}

public partial class Login : MyPage{
         //want to set title from Here
}
```

Thanks 
Ravi Mittal

Comment: I assume each derived class will have its own title?

Comment: What are you looking to do, have part of the title set by your base class and part of it set in your derived class? Otherwise you can just set this.Title like @Leo's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set it just via [Title](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.ui.page.title%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e){ 
      //do some basic opeation
    this.Title = "Some title";
}
```

If you want to make it different for each sub page, you can make abstract property

```
public abstract class MyPage : Page
{
    public abstract string PageTitle {get;}

    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e){ 
          //do some basic opeation
        this.Title = PageTitle;
        base.OnInit(e);
    }

}
```

and sample page

```
public class SubPage : MyPage
{
    public override string PageTitle
    {
        get { return "Some sub title";}
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, you cannot add abstract property in non-abstract class.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. fixed it. it's hard to write code without IDE

Comment: You shouldn't handle events from a base class in a derived class. You aren't guaranteed execution order. You should override the base methods instead.

Comment: fixed. it was just example of Title usage

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with doing `this.Title`?

I'm not too sure if you're setting the `AutoEventWireup` property but I'd suggest you to override the `OnInit` method rather than using `Page_Init`

Comment: i think i am fail to understand what my question is

Comment: Yeah, probably.  That's why the answer is exactly the same after it was edited to use my approach :)